# Can't get ID to do delete method (VueX,VueJS)

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I follow this guy to do my task:"Call an API to delete items"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjRst4qduzM&t=967s, start at 12:35.
According this guy said, If you wanna implement delete method there are 2 steps: Firstly, you delete items from state by get ID then use filter method to filter the id you selected.(but when you reload page item still available).Secondly, you call an api to server to delete item in server.

I get in stuck in step one, I can't get ID to delete though before I can select ID to choose company.
This is my component

```
  <div>

    <v-data-table

      v-model="selected"

      :search="search"

      :headers="headers"

      :items="items"

      show-select

      hide-default-footer

      disable-pagination

      class="elevation-1"

    >

      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">

        <v-menu offset-y>

          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">

            <v-btn class="ma-2" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" icon>

              <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>

            </v-btn>

          </template>

          <v-list>

            <v-list-item @click="editCompany(item)">

              <span>Edit company</span></v-list-item

            >

            <v-list-item @click="deleteCompany()">

              <span style="color: #e12d39"> Delete company</span>

            </v-list-item>

          </v-list>

        </v-menu>

      </template>

    </v-data-table>

  </div>

</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {

  props: {

    items: {

      type: Array,

    },

    search: { type: String },

  },

  data() {

    return {

      headers: [

        { text: "Name", align: "start", value: "name" },

        { text: "Phone Number", value: "phoneNumber" },

        { text: "Website", value: "website" },

        { text: "Address", value: "address" },

        { text: "Currency", value: "currency" },

        { text: "Image Name", value: "imageName" },

        { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false },

      ],

    };

  },

  computed: {

    ...mapGetters({ deletedCompany: "companies/deletedCompany" }),

  },

  methods: {

    deleteCompany(delID) {

      console.log("dispatch:", delID);

      this.$store.dispatch("companies/deleteCompany", delID);

    },

  },

};

</script>
```

and this is my store
import NProgress from "nprogress";

```
export const namespaced = true;

import Vue from "vue";

import Vuex from "vuex";

import { create } from "@/http/companies";

import VueToast from "vue-toast-notification";

import "vue-toast-notification/dist/theme-sugar.css";

import { getCompanies } from "@/http/companies";

// import { deleteCompanies } from "@/http/companies";

Vue.use(Vuex);

Vue.use(VueToast);

export const state = {

  companies: [],

  selectedCompanyId: "",

};

export const getters = {

  allCompanies: (state) => state.companies,

  selectedCompanyId: (state) => state.selectedCompanyId,

  deletedCompanyId: (state) => state.deletedCompanyId,

  selectedCompany: (state) => state.companies.find((c) => c.id === state.selectedCompanyId),

  deletedCompany: (state) => state.companies.filter((c) => c.id != state.deletedCompanyId)

};

export const mutations = {

  GET_COMPANIES(state, companies) {

    state.companies = companies;

  },

  DELETE_COMPANIES(state, deletedCompanyId) {

    console.log("mutations:", deletedCompanyId)

    state.deletedCompanyId = deletedCompanyId;

  },

  SET_SELECTED_COMPANY_ID(state, selectedCompanyId) {

    console.log(selectedCompanyId)

    state.selectedCompanyId = selectedCompanyId

  },

  STORE_ID(state, payload) {

    state.routeId = payload;

  },

};

export const actions = {

  storeID({ commit }, payload) {

    commit("STORE_ID", payload);

  },

  getCompanies({ commit }) {

    return getCompanies(NProgress.start()).then((response) => {

      commit("GET_COMPANIES", response.data);

      NProgress.done();

    });

  },

  selectCompany({ commit }, companyId) {

    commit("SET_SELECTED_COMPANY_ID", companyId, NProgress.start());

    console.log("đây là id", companyId)

    NProgress.done();

  },

  deleteCompany({ commit }, delId) {

    console.log("actions:", delId)

    return commit("DELETE_COMPANIES", delId);

  },

  registerCompany({ commit }, companyInfor) {

    return create(companyInfor)

      .then(() => {

        Vue.$toast.open({

          message: "Create company successfully!",

          type: "success",

          duration: 3000,

          dismissible: true,

          position: "top-right",

        });

      })

      .catch((error) => {

        commit("");

        Vue.$toast.open({

          message: error,

          type: "error",

          duration: 3000,

          dismissible: true,

          position: "top-right",

        });

      });

  },

};
```

https://www.loom.com/share/1eb12a448aca41df8e4c77cdc8931002?focus_title=1&muted=1&from_recorder=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the id via the click event  handler `<v-list-item @click="deleteCompany(item.id)">`:

```
    methods: {

     deleteCompany(delID) {

      console.log("dispatch:", delID);

      this.$store.dispatch("companies/deleteCompany", delID);
      // or this.$store.dispatch("companies/deleteCompany", delID);
    },

  },
```

Comment: tks for your response sir, it's still not working sir ~~ can you help me

Comment: tks you verymuch sir <3 I'm so appreciated. It's working, but dont know why the company still display not be deleted. Now i can log ID

Comment: you should add `state.companies.filter((c) => c.id != state.deletedCompanyId)` inside your mutation `DELETE_COMPANIES`

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to pass parameter as item_id to function

```
          <v-list-item @click="deleteCompany(item)">
```

perhaps this will do the trick

Comment: tks for your response, I added my param (delID) to this function. It's still now working ~~